# default axis steps per unit Makerbot replicator 2

Tags: makerbot, marlin

I can not find anywhere default steps per unit for Makerbot replicaor 2. I'm using Ramp V1.4 instead original board and need to know default steps :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Replicator 2 and 2x use 18 tooth GT2 pulleys, 1/16 microstepping, and 200 steps/rev steppers. That makes the proper steps/mm value 88.888889.

Note that Makerbot used ~88.56 steps/mm in their defaults, which is the value you get if you calculate from the belt+pulley pitch diameter from the Gates GT2 specs. But this is the value you use for calculating belt length required in a closed loop, not for steps/mm. The 88.88... number is more accurate.

Comment: Hey once again, what about z axis then?

Comment: Z is 400 steps/mm. (8mm lead, 1/16 microstepping, 200 steps/mm motor.) Sidenote, make sure you don't over-drive the Z stepper with plug-in drivers, it's only rated to about 0.4A.

Comment: @RyanCarlyle FYI minor typo above, you say 200 steps/mm for Z but I think you mean steps/rev since you already state Z is 400 steps/mm. Thank you for accurate numbers though!

Comment: I've been referring to this answer for years and it worked until I switched to Klipper where rotation distance is calculated using microsteps. Using 1/16 moved double the distance. Microstepping is 1/8 on 2 and 2X ("Replicator 1 is double that due to 1/16th stepping VS 1/8 but both use the same pulleys") according to: https://groups.google.com/g/makerbot/c/zWllJKQMrZY. Setting microsteps to 1/8 and not changing rotation distance (36 worked, and is close to the default, 40) made Klipper move correctly.